# Fade Out a Table returned by Ajax request in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I have a jsp page that lists down orders pertaining to a customer. On clicking the order number, the details of the order is shown through an ajax request to another jsp page (which fetches the data from Oracle and returns an HTMLtable). This HTML table is put as innerHTML of a div element in the first jsp page.

A screen shot of the UI is below:

[image: List of orders with order no. 1 details]

I want that when the user clicks on close, the details screen should fadeout. The id of close (which is HTML `<font>` tag) is close.

I have tried the following:

1. ```js
   $("#close").click(function(){
   $("#order_detail").fadeOut();
   });
   ```
2. ```js
   $("#close").on('click',function(){
   $("#order_detail").fadeOut();
   });
   ```

But neither is working. How do I manipulate this dynamic HTML Table returned by Ajax from with jquery on the first page.

Comment: pls show your ajax code

Comment: Try this: `$('body').on('click', '#close', function(){
$("#order_detail").fadeOut();
});` assuming that `#close` is not in the `DOM` when event binding takes place..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you stated it is a dynamic HTML Table returned by Ajax, my guess is when your jquery code loads, there isn't any html tag by the id of 'close' so jquery couldn't find the element by id of close

you can try using the onclick attribute in the tag calling a javascript function
like

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="close" onclick="close_ui();">close</a>
```

or put your code in your ajax request like

```
$.get('url', function(retObj){
      $('table').html(retObj);
      $("#close").on('click',function(){
           $("#order_detail").fadeOut();
      });

 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("#close").on('click',function(){
  $("#order_detail").fadeOut("normal",function(){
   $("#order_detail").remove();
  });
});
```